# Need new way to put apps in j2me phone

Tags: installation, java-me

This morning I discovered that the one way known to work to get an app into my java phone, rumkin.com, has stopped working. I need an alternative.

The phone I'm developing for is an LG Rumor Reflex, model LN272. It does not have WiFi, and attempts to point browsers at 127.0.0.1 have always failed. So the only way to install an app is through the internet.

I do not have a website of my own.

mobilefish.com claims to do what I need, including generate a .jad file automatically. However, half the time it refuses to upload the file, claiming that I didn't enter the correct code when in fact I did; and the rest of the time, attempting to download the .jad file fails.

Google searches have turned up the now defunct rumkin, mobilefish, and results that have nothing to do with what I need.

Can anyone point me to either a phone upload site that still/actually works, or some means of installing through the usb cable that works. Also has anyone had any success doing this through dropbox or similar storage sites?

Comment: Well you can forget about Dropbox. It doesn't work on the phone. Maybe some other website that serves the same purpose will; but I don't know of any offhand.

Comment: Are you sure it runs JavaME? According to this site, it doesnt: https://www.gsmarena.com/lg_rumor_reflex__ln272-4625.php

Comment: It runs JavaME. I've been using phones like it for several years. It's a Boost Mobile phone, on their now discontinued Pay Go plan with internet add-on, grandfathered in at 10 cents a minute or text and 35 cents a day for internet. Android and Blackberry phones are not allowed on this plan.

Comment: I used to use Bluetooth a lot when transferring my MIDlets to phones for testing. This worked on all newer phones as far as I remember. The older ones requires OTA installation though.